# Canvas and SharePoint dropdown menu conflict in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint, google-chrome, canvas

I got a problem when I use canvas in SharePoint. In Chrome, when I open a new tab or a new instance of Chrome and if the current page contains one or more canvas, the dropdown menu of SharePoint doesn't work. Here is a simple demo:
[image: In Chrome]

When I put the mouse on the "News", it doesn't show up.
But it will be ok when I refresh the page.
Here is the expected result in Firefox:
[image: In Firefox]

Here is the demo code to draw the rectangle:

```
function drawRectangle(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        if(canvas.getContext){
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
  }
}
```

And I also found that if I delete the "ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200)", only leave "var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");", the problem still exists. Will you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not that much SharePoint related and it would help if you showed the code which is opening the News menu.